# Combining columns and rows in overleaf

Tags: multicolumn, multirow, makecell

I would like to put "U.S. census" in the middle of the given space, and also "GroupA" as well. Currently it's somewhat shifted. How should I combine the rows?

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
\toprule
& U.S. Census & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Study2} \\
&             & GroupA & \multicolumn{4}{c}{GroupB} \\
&             &        & A & B & C & D \\

\bottomrule   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Current image]

I tried multirow and makecell functions but both didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "middle of the given space".

Comment: Oh sorry for that. The word "U.S. Census" is skewed upward, but I want to put that in the same line as "Group B" so that it could be in the middle of three rows. Please check out the Current image file.

Comment: Than you should move "U.S. Census" from the first row to the second. Why you have empty first column? More background of your table will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Is one of the following two solutions (close to) what you're after?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption*{First possibility}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c r rrrr @{}}
\toprule
 && \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Study2} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-7}
XYZ & U.S. Census & Group A & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Group B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-7}
 && & A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
% more table stuff 
\\
\bottomrule   
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5in}
\caption*{Second possibility}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c r rrrr @{}}
\toprule
 && \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Study2} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-7}
XYZ & U.S. Census &  & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Group B} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-7}
 && Group A & A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
% more table stuff 
\\
\bottomrule   
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Would it be possible to shift "Group A" in the middle of second and third rows?

Comment: Oh, I meant moving "GroupA" slightly downward so that it sets in the middle of the line between "GroupB" and "A, B, C, D" since the column with GroupA has a remaining space.

Comment: @snowman - Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I meant exactly mixing those two solutions that you provided.  Group A is too upward in the first solution and too downward in the second solution - Would it be possible to put it exactly in the middle?

Comment: @snowman - Absolutely. Be sure to load the [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package in the preamble. Then, take the first solution, replace `Group A` with `\multirow{2.3}{*}{Group A}`, and delete `\cmidrule(lr){3-3}`.

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lrrrrrr}}
\toprule
&\SetCell[r=3]{c} U.S. Census & \SetCell[c=5]{c} Study2 &&&& \\
&& \SetCell[r=2]{c} GroupA & \SetCell[c=4]{c} GroupB &&&\\
& & & A & B & C & D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lrrrrrr}}
\toprule
&\SetCell[r=3]{c} U.S. Census & \SetCell[c=5]{c} Study2 &&&& \\
\cmidrule{3-7}
&& \SetCell[r=2]{c} GroupA & \SetCell[c=4]{c} GroupB &&&\\
\cmidrule{4-7}
& & & A & B & C & D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]